# Manually Change Windows Battery Percentage

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, battery

I'm in an awkward problem. I have a laptop with a faulty battery whose battery percentage doesn't go beyond 3% doesn't matter how much time I leave it for charging. Now I need to flash new BIOS firmware which requires at least 10% battery life. Now I know my laptop won't ever go beyond that percentage. What can be the possible solution without changing the battery of course? Is there some place where Windows store battery percentage? Any way to hack there? Or maybe fool the BIOS software?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro x86.

Comment: This can probably not be done. But taking out the battery all the way and running just on power from the wall won't work?

Comment: Unfortunately, after removing battery, software tells to insert battery.

Comment: Buy a new battery.

Comment: Best practice for flashing the BIOS on a laptop has always been to do so with it plugged in to AC power and with a fully charged battery. It is assumed that the battery would be good. Power loss during a BIOS flash is virtually guaranteed to corrupt the BIOS leaving you in a very difficult position. Best to replace the battery. I see little reason why Windows would provide a means of overriding battery charge information but good reasons why it should not.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with my Samsung Galaxy Book 10.6. Did you find any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @Mahdi No I didn’t.

Comment: I'm in this same Catch-22, but on linux. The point of upgrading BIOS is that I hope the computer can then talk to the new battery. Right now it reads 0% no matter what I do, but if I unplug the computer, it stays on and works like the battery is charged.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my Alienware laptop and Dell uses the InsydeFlash
utility

This is how I got past the battery check.

1. Close all applications
2. Go to Run (windows + R) and type %temp%. Delete all files that you can and those that are still in use and can't be deleted, ignore them (skip)
3. Run your bios flash program and don't close the modal dialog box
4. Now go back to the temp folder and you'll find a new folder created by the bios flash program extractor.
5. Copy this folder to some other directory, like say your Documents directory
6. Close the bios flash program by dealing with it's dialog prompt
7. Go to the directory you just copied (Which has the extracted contents of the bios flash extractor utility), there you will find a platforms.ini
8. Open that file in a text editor, and change the BatteryCheck flag to 0
9. Save and close
10. Rename the same file to **platform.ini** from platforms.ini
11. Run the InsydeFlash.exe and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

To display the battery level, Windows queries the battery hardware. Also the app that requires your battery be charged up to 10% uses the same method. (Hell, it probably uses the same API.)

So, no, you cannot "edit" the battery level manually ... at least, not without accomplishing extraordinary deeds that usually happen in movies only (like some high-tech modding on the battery hardware or subverting Windows kernel).

Try shutting down your computer completely, removing the battery, plugging it into a power socket and then upgrading the firmware.

Comment: Unfortunately, after removing battery, software tells to insert battery.

Answer (score 0):

as for @havokentity answer, It worked. I did have to do some additional steps

1. Set BatteryBounds to 1 (Not require maybe)
2. set platform.ini file read-only (Important)

Answer (score 0):

For Dell and Alienware something more simple and still working on 2021 may 20th with latest bios updates.

1. Download your bios update file and copy it i.e. to C:
2. Run Command Prompt as administrator
3. Type `cd \` and press enter
4. Type `biosupdate.exe /forceit` (replace biosupdate with the corresponding name)

The process will ask you to restart, after rebooting your bios will be updated.

This might also work for other brands (Toshiba, Lenovo...), but you will have to find the force switch which could be different depending on the brand.

**Warning: if your battery reaches 0% and there is an electric shutdown during the update your computer could become unusable.**